# Eclipse Data Tools Platform (DTP) Select * limit

Tags: eclipse, oracle, eclipse-dtp

I have a DB in Oracle11g and i use Eclipse with Eclipse Data Tools Platform (DTP). I try to select all rows in one table with this

```
select * from <table_name>;
```

but it only return 500 rows. There's any way to pass this limitation?
Thanks

Comment: just a suggestion: switch to Toad Plugin. Once tried that I've never ever get back to DTP. http://www.quest.com/toad-extension-for-eclipse/

Comment: Another suggestion: use SQL Developer. Do you really need to access database from eclipse?

Comment: @SzilardBarany no, its not mandatory.

Comment: i will try both suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of fetched rows can be configured from the following places in Eclipse DTP:

- View menu (Ctrl-F10) / Preferences... / Max row count
- Window / Preferences / Data Management / SQL Development / SQL Results View / Max row count